# Tumblr Android - Post Image using Oauth

Tags: android, oauth, tumblr

I have an app that shares pictures via Facebook, Twitter and Tumblr. I was successfully able to share pictures through Facebook and Twitter. However, Tumblr simply refuses to oblige. Are there any libraries available for Tumblr? Currently, I have retrieved a user token and a secret via a callback through a webview. But, I am at sea at how to post an image to a blog on Tumblr. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

I have looked into the Tumblr apis, but the documentation is rather vague. http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog_methods. The requests need a 'blog name', which I am not sure how to obtain.

To delve further, here is a sample post url, listed in the documentation - *api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/post*. Now, the problem here is that 'base-hostname' wouldn't be provided by the user when he/she is logging in. So, I am clueless at this point as how to acquire it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once authenticated and you have your Token and Secret Token call http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info this will return the users blog's and there URL's.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Action Send Intent? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND

Comment: Yes, I have. But that doesn't unfortunately suit my requirement. My app allows user to select channels through which they would want to share. By using ACTION_SEND, I am limiting the options to whatever is available on the phone - for example, not every user has a Tumblr app installed on his/her phone.